# saving second result set from a SelectMethod

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

We have a Gridview, which gets filled via a DataSource. The datasource's SelectMethod is a function in the BL class, which calls a Stored Procedure that returns 2 Result-sets. The first result set is supposed to fill the gridview, so it's returned via the "return" keyword, and that works fine. The second result set is for later use (we're not separating them into 2 SP's because the query applies the same logic to get both result sets, and it's a long logic, so we don't want to run it twice). Our question is how to save the second result-set for the later use.

We initially thought of creating a global member in the BL class, and saving the result-set to it. But the problem is that when we need to use the second result-set, we're not in the same class where the gridview is, and that other class creates an instance of its own of the BL class, and of course that object doesn't have the data (the data is in the object created by the aspx page in which the gridview resides).

So then we thought of passing an "out" parameter the datasource's SelectMethod, and the method would save the second result set to that out parameter. But that's not working. I think we don't know how to tell the method that a parameter is "out". The way we pass the other parameters is by defining a method that is attached to the OnSelecting event, and then we pass them so:

e.InputParameters["schoolCode"] = currentSchoolCode;

e.InputParameters["levelCode"] = currentLayer;

Etc. However, we don't know how to tell the method that a parameter is "out". When we googled a little, all we could find was how to tell the method if a parameter is an output parameter - that is, passed to the SP as an output parameter. But that is not the case here.

So we will be very grateful if you help us find the solution for:
"Telling" the method that a certain parameter is "out", in order to get the value into it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... not quite understand your concern, but, how about this? pass your dataset to presentation layer and then:

```
dataset.Tables(0)
dataset.Tables(1)
```

or

```
DataReader.NextResult()
```